# Each ordered semigroup is cancellative: reference?

Tags: reference-request, order-theory, semigroups

It is easy enough to show that $a+b < a+c\Rightarrow b < c$ holds in totally ordered semigroups. Indeed this must be very well known. Can anyone please provide a reference for this result? A textbook will do!

Proof: Suppose $c \ge b$. Then $a+c \ge a+b$ as + respects the order. We are done by contraposition.

Comment: A textbook please.

Comment: This might be an example of "folklore" in the sense that it might not have a reference. (See Howie's "Fundamentals of Semigroup Theory" for a use of the term "folklore" in this way.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**. This is an answer to the initial question of the OP, which has been changed later on.

This is not true. Actually, the fact that $+$ respects order just means that $a \leqslant b$ implies $a+c \leqslant b+c$.

For a counterexample to your claim, take $M = \{0, 1\}$ under the usual multiplication and the usual order $0 < 1$.

**EDIT**. The answer to the new question is "yes", but the proof should be

> Suppose that $c \leqslant b$. Then $a+c \leqslant a+b$ as + respects the
>   order. The claim follows by contraposition.

Comment: I am seriously confused now. First of all, I think you mean addition instead of multiplication in your last line, right?
Then, using your rule, from $0<1$ we get at least that $0+1 \le 1+1 = 0$. So it looks like in your claimed counterexample, + doesn't respect the ordering at all.

Comment: No, I mean multiplication, but if you prefer an additive notation, just define it as follows: $0+0=0$, $1+0=0+1=1+1=1$. Think of this addition as the Boolean operation "or", $0$ as false and $1$ as true.

Comment: Apologies, I realize now that I messed up the inequality signs! I actually meant it the other way around - see the new version of the question.

Comment: Thank you! I took the liberty of slightly editing your final proof, as we do not need a proof by contradiction here. Sorry for (again...) messing up the inequality signs, this time the direction. Of course, I was actually looking for a reference, but the proof is so short that I will just replicate it when I need it.